# DateTime::createFromFormat returns NULL

Tags: php, date, null, format

I have the following php code:

```
$dateString = 'Okt 10, 2014';  // month names are not english
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'); 

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('M j, Y', $dateString, $timezone);

if($date == null) {
    echo "NULL";
} else {
    var_dump($date);
}
```

It returns `NULL`

Isn't the createFromFormat Function made for cases like this, or did I do something wrong?

Comment: I don't believe createFromFormat() will accept any text terms such as day name or month name in any language other than English.... the error you made was in assuming that simply setting a timezone would automagically enable a built-in universal translator.... you need PHP's StarTrek or Tardis extensions enabled for that

Comment: too bad :(
Then I have to find out why the date is stored in German format in the first place... 
Thanks for clearing that up for me.